# Cleaning Date data, changing the data to date format and fixing the missing values

Tags: excel, date, format, visualization, data-cleaning

I am working on a dataset in excel that has the date data in wrong format and some missing data, how do i clean the data, change the date to the right format and fix the missing values?
I tried to use "Find and replace function" to change the field to date format, some rows changed while some didn't. I also tried to use DATE formula, RIGHT, MID and LEFT to pick the date, all to no avail.
I'm pretty new to Visualization and data Analytics, please. I'm presently working on Excel. I need help, please
This is part of my dataset:
08/04/1970
14/05/1969
12/08/1969
15/02/1972
08/08/1972
05/08/1969
06/12/1969
06/02/1968

Comment: Share the input data format, what is the format and type (string, date) and the expected format you want for each value base on the new format and the destination type value (string or date). Please update your question based on the information requested.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is typically a daunting and manual task, as there is no way to know if, say, 08/04/1970  is of April or August.

Comment: Do you have access to the original CSV or TEXT file? If so, it is a simple matter of properly **importing** the file instead of **opening** it.